# What is this seed like build up on my grape vine?

Tags: identification, grape-vine, safety

What is this seed like build up on my grape vine?
Is it safe to eat the grapes still? [image: the actual vines in question]

Answer (score 1):

A stab in the dark, but it's not some sort of scale insect infestation is it? And the plant's reaction to such an infestation? The two circled things in the blow up of your photo (below) look vaguely like scale insects.
[image]